# How can i create a folder on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ using IPAddress of my machine?

Tags: c#

How can i create a folder on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ using IPAddress of my machine ?
The ff code does not seem to work for me.It gives error : The given path's format is not supported.

```
          `     string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
                string IPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath + "//GM_KanbanTracking/" + IPAddress); error     here The given path's format is not supported.
                StreamWriter w;
                w = File.CreateText(appPath + "//GM_KanbanTracking/" + IPAddress +     "/test.txt");
                w.WriteLine(fileContents.ToString());
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();
```

`

Comment: "ff code"? What does that mean?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that IP addresses are not unique to clients. Think mobile. Think offices sharing a single connection. The list goes on...

Answer (score 0):

While you may have a regular IPv4 address (e.g. 192.168.1.1), the host address in this case may be an IPv6 address that looks something like this: `2001:0:9d38:953c:cad:20fd:3f57:fa08`. Since colons (`:`) aren't allowed in filenames, you have to change them to something else, like this:

```
string IPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Replace(":", "_");
```

This will convert my IP address to `2001_0_9d38_953c_cad_20fd_3f57_fa08`, which is a valid filename.

If you have IPv4 addresses, your problem lies in the rest of your path specification. Not only are colons invalid characters, but so are slashes (`/`). Your sample code shows slashes which must be backslashes in order to work.

Comment: i got what you saying ,but what i need is that on wwwroot folder there must a FOLDER with my machine IPaddress like (10.19.13.92) inside that folder there must be a textfile contains all data to be printed.

Comment: Are you using `\ ` for your path separators and not `/ `?